# Joining Tables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have four tables that I want to join and display the output all together.  I'm not sure how the syntax works for Oracle SQL Developer.  I know this is an easy question for a programmer and I was hoping someone can make a suggestion on how the code might look like.

The **tables** are:

```
JNL1
JNL2
JNL3
JNL4
```

The key that is common between all four of these tables is `ItemID`.

How would the query look like?  Thanks

Comment: The syntax isn't determined by the tool (which is SQL Developer) but by the database system (which is Oracle). Check out the Oracle manual on how to write a join: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm#i2054012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of join you want (outer or not)  but you can use default SQL syntax.

For example, joining without the `JOIN` keyword:

```
select * from JNL1, JNL2, JNL3, JNL4,
where 
JNL1.ItemID = JNL2.ItemID AND
JNL2.ItemID = JNL3.ItemID AND
JNL3.ItemID = JNL4.ItemID;
```

Additionally you can make use of multiple `INNER JOINS` e.g.

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM JNL1 AS a
INNER 
  JOIN JNL2 AS b
    ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
INNER 
  JOIN JNL2 AS c
     ON c.ItemID = b.ItemID
INNER 
  JOIN JNL2 AS d
     ON d.ItemID = c.ItemID
```

Answer (score 2):

It works in Oracle as it would in other DB engines :

```
SELECT *
FROM JNL1 j1
INNER JOIN JNL2 j2 ON j1.ItemID = j2.ItemID
INNER JOIN JNL3 j3 ON j1.ItemID = j3.ItemID
INNER JOIN JNL4 j4 ON j1.ItemID = j4.ItemID
```

One typical Oracle syntax exists when you want to `LEFT JOIN` :

Standard SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM JNL1 j1
LEFT JOIN JNL2 j2 ON j1.ItemID = j2.ItemID
LEFT JOIN JNL3 j3 ON j1.ItemID = j3.ItemID
LEFT JOIN JNL4 j4 ON j1.ItemID = j4.ItemID
```

is equivalent to this Oracle syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM JNL1 j1,
JNL2 j2,
JNL3 j3,
JNL4 j4,
WHERE j1.ItemID=j2.ItemID(+)
AND j1.ItemID=j3.ItemID(+)
AND j1.ItemID=j4.ItemID(+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the rows from *all* the tables, and if the columns are the same in each table, `UNION ALL` will work. Note that this isn't a `JOIN` in the database sense, though it kind of is in an English sense:

```
SELECT * FROM JNL1
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM JNL2
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM JNL3
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM JNL4
```

You can add an `ORDER BY` to the end if needed.

`UNION` is similar to `UNION ALL`, but it will omit rows where all of the values are duplicates.

Comment: It gives me this error when I run that: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

Comment: OK, that basically means I misunderstood your question. I thought you might mean "join" in the sense of "append" - I guessed because there were no table definitions, and I guessed wrong :) The other answers use actual database joins so they're probably what you want.