# Oracle SQL query joining two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I am attempting to do the following:

I have two tables I am joining

1. SKU # table
2. Price table

And the primary key for the SKU and Price table is the 'item #'. I am retrieving all records that have multiple item #'s for one SKU #  (as seen in the query below).

The results show all the item #'s with one SKU #.  Also, the Unit Price is also shown for each item #.

I want to retrieve any SKU and all associated item #'s where the price is different (but not any records where the price is the same).

NOTE: Unit Price is only in Price table.  SKU # is only in SKU table.

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve just the SKU and all associated item #'s where the price is different?

```
select 
    ivitm ITEM#, ivaitm PART#, ivcitm SKU#, iveftj EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
    ivexdj EXPIRATION_DATE, (bpuprc/10000) Unit_Price
from 
    proddta.f4104 --SKU
join 
    proddta.f4106 on bpitm = ivitm     --Price
where 
    ivcitm in (select ivcitm 
               from proddta.f4104 
               where ivexdj >= (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYDDD'))-1900000) 
               having count(*) >= 2 
               group by ivcitm)
    and bpcgid = '1'
    and bpexdj >= (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYDDD'))-1900000)
    and ivan8 = '444'
    and ivxrt = 'C'
    and ivcitm != ' '
    and ivcitm != ' '
group by 
    ivitm, ivaitm, ivcitm, iveftj, ivexdj, bpuprc
order by 
    ivcitm, ivaitm
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you might consider giving your database objects less cryptic names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining Tables in Oracle SQL Developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238038/joining-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: Can you please post an example with data in your tables and needed result